# json response not reflecting in view?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I call a webservice which returns JSON response. I want to bind this json data in to view using ng-repeat. 
**I am using the same controller for both the screens**.

This is how the flow looks like :

- I call a webservice and get json.
- I move to the other screen using $state.go('screen2')
- Here I try to bind my json with my html.

My code :

```
angular.module('controller').controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, $state, $http) {
$scope.myList;
$scope.getUserList = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: someurl,
        }).then(function(response) {
            //success
            if (response.data.status == "OK") { 
                    $scope.myList = response.data.data;
                    $state.go('screen2');
            }
        }, function(response) {
            alert('failed');
        });
    }
```

My View(screen2) :

```
<ion-view view-title="Select User">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-user">
    <h1 class="title">Select User</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="mainWrap">
    <div class="text-title">
      Lorel ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="list user">
      <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#" ng-repeat="v in myList">
        <i class="icon ion-wifi"></i>
        {{v.name}}
      </a>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

When I [hardcode](http://plnkr.co/edit/FW4Mcs29dbO89Y6XykdH?p=preview) and attach that json data directly to the controller's scope. Everything works fine. But when I bind the same json in $http's response ..nothing works.

Webservice response :

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "lorel",
            "type": "off"
        },
        {
            "name": "edimax",
            "type": "on"
        },
        {
            "name": "ipsum",
            "type": "on"
        },
        {
            "name": "blah blah",
            "type": "on"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.myList` is scoped to a single controller.
Every `$scope` member is bound to a controller, which should be bound to a view.

I suspect that you're sharing the same controller for 2 different views; maybe something like this:

```
  $stateProvider

  .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      controller: 'homeController',
  })

  .state('screen2', {
      url: '/screen2',
      templateUrl: 'screen2.html',
      controller: 'homeController',
  });
```

That is not a good thing to do. It's always better to have a controller for a view.

Anyway, since you want to share data you have to use some sort of cache. 
What you can do is to use a service.

You can create something like this:

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.services', [])
    .factory('dataService', dataService);

  dataService.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];

  /* @ngInject */
  function dataService($q, $http) {

    var service = {
      myList: [],
      fetchData: fetchData
    };

    return (service);

    function fetchData() {

      // Do some sort of $http request and fill the list.

      var deferred = $q.defer();

      this.myList = [];

      this.myList.push({name: 'AAA'});
      this.myList.push({name: 'BBB'});
      this.myList.push({name: 'CCC'});

      deferred.resolve(this.myList);

      return deferred.promise;

    }

  }

})();
```

This service has got a collection `myList` which is filled when the method `fetchData` is called. I've used a promise to simulate the $http request in your controller.

Your controller should look like this:

```
angular.module('controller').controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, $state, dataService) {

    $scope.myList = dataService.myList;

    $scope.getUserList = function() {
        dataService.getUserList()
          .then(function(response) {
            //success
            if (response.data.status == "OK") { 
                    // $scope.myList = response.data.data;
                    $state.go('screen2');
            }
        }, function(response) {
            alert('failed');
        });
    }

});
```

You need to inject the service `dataService` and request the list so you can filled the array in the scope of your controller:

```
$scope.myList = dataService.myList;
```

When you call the method `$scope.getUserList()` in your controller, dataService will fetch the data:

```
dataService.getUserList()
```

and fill the internal list, so when you're going to the different state the dataService will have the list filled and the scope will be loaded with the new data:

```
$scope.myList = dataService.myList;
```

This is a plunker where you can test the [experiment](http://plnkr.co/edit/0fH6puHlxk9vBM10Ag6z?p=preview).

PS: I've used the same controller for a different state/view but, again, I wouldn't do that.

Comment: Thx. So it worked whenI used a service. But when I didn't what caused the problem? just wanted to know some fundamentals.

Comment: @JayeshJain: Try to recreate your problem in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) and I can try to explain. Cheers.